# Hibernate criteria, using associations to return results by restrictions

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-criteria

Hi guys i have this mapping inside the Customer entity:

```
@OneToOne(cascade={javax.persistence.CascadeType.ALL})
@JoinColumn(name="address")
private Address address;
```

And then i have this method in my DAO class:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public List<Customer> getCustomersFromThisAddress() throws Exception{
    sessao = null;
    try{
        sessao = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        Customer customer= new Customer();

        Criteria criteria = sessao.createCriteria(customer.getClass())
                    .createAlias("address", "a")
                        .add(Restrictions.ilike("a.area", "bedford"));
        return (List<Customer>) criteria.setResultTransformer(Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY).list();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return null;
    } finally {
        sessao.close();
    }
}
```

I would like to return all customers from the bedford area... I am new to Hibernate and Criteria, please help.

Comment: do you get an error or just empty list?

Comment: @MaciejKowalski empty list

Answer (score 1):

You have to remember about two things when using the `ilike`:

**a)** The underlying database must be able to support it or have an equivalent function.

**b)** Without specifying `MatchMode` or adding `%` symbols to the second argument, your statement is just a case-insensitive equals.

So if you want to search for a text that simply contains somewhere the `bedford` string then use one of the following:

```
.add(Restrictions.ilike("a.area", "%bedford%"));
```

or

```
.add(Restrictions.ilike("a.area", "bedford", MatchMode.ANYWHERE));
```

Answer (score 0):

I was getting an empty list '[]' I realized  that I made a mistake in the .add(Restriction.. line!!
the 'area' column data, in the Address table are all recorded as 'Bedford'..

after reading this: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/hibernate/hibernate_criteria_queries.htm

I found that I just needed to change

```
Criteria criteria = sessao.createCriteria(customer.getClass())
                .createAlias("address", "a")
                    .add(Restrictions.ilike("a.area", "bedford"));
```

to

```
Criteria criteria = sessao.createCriteria(customer.getClass())
                .createAlias("address", "a")
                    .add(Restrictions.like("a.area", "bedford"));
```

to return my list... Hope this will help others!!